# Hide subheader on scroll down in Ionic/Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In an Angular/Ionic app, I'm trying to create the effect where scrolling down the screen hides the subheader as shown in the codepen below.

**Problem:** However when you stop scrolling, the subheader appears which is not what we want. We only want the subheader to appear when we scroll up `N` pixels, not when we stop scrolling.

http://codepen.io/danbhala/pen/ChIEt

Any ideas how we can fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the above is what OP was looking for, as you still want the menus to appear on scroll up no matter where in the page, the bug causing the menu to appear on stop was a simple operator issue, where it should be

```
if ($rootScope.slideHeaderPrevious > e.detail.scrollTop - start)
```

instead of

```
if ($rootScope.slideHeaderPrevious >= e.detail.scrollTop - start)
```

which makes sense when you consider that the previous value will be equal on stop causing the condition to be true

working here
http://codepen.io/markfarl/pen/NNYyjQ

Answer (score 0):

I have made changes to the existing code to meet your requirements

**Script**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $ionicScrollDelegate, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.slideHeader = false;
  $rootScope.pixelLimit = 100;
})

.directive('scrollWatch', function($rootScope) {
  return function(scope, elem, attr) {

    elem.bind('scroll', function(e) {
      if(e.detail.scrollTop < $rootScope.pixelLimit) {
        $rootScope.slideHeader = false;
      } else {
        $rootScope.slideHeader = true;
      }
      $rootScope.$apply();
    });
  };
});
```

If your top scroll position exceeds the limit set with `$rootScope.pixelLimit` the subheader is hidden, Otherwise visible. You can set your own limit with `$rootScope.pixelLimit`.

**[See Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOXLzY?editors=001)**